# Rails 3: Run thin server without gem 'thin' in gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

Is it possible to run thin server (gem 'thin') without referencing gem 'thin' in gemfile?

he problem is that on Windows blunder add dependencies in gemfile.lock (eventmachine 1.0.0.beta.4.1 - the only version for windows) that heroku hosting can not accept while push fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding that dependency in the development group only in your gemfile:

```
group :development do
  eventmachine, '1.0.0.beta.4.1'
end
```

That should prevent bundler from trying to install that on heroku.

Comment: Yes, they are already in :development group (bundler on heroku doesn't try to install them when there is no gemfile.lock in push), but the problem not in gemfile, but in gemfile.lock - I created the workaround  (bash script that deletes eventmachine from gemfile.lock before push) but I wanted to find out more clear way.